# how can I do integration testing with the twitter gem and capybara?

Tags: ruby, twitter, integration-testing, capybara, omniauth

I'm writing an example app using Devise + OmniAuth for logging in and the twitter gem to get the users name. I'd like to add a few integration tests but I don't know what to do with the twitter gem.

Here's my user model (which is where most of the logic is found):

```
def build_authentication(omniauth)
  # If the provider is twitter, get additional information                    
  # to build a user profile.                                                  
  if omniauth['provider'] == 'twitter'         
    self.build_twitter(omniauth)
  end

  # now put the authentication in the database                                
  authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'],
                        :uid => omniauth['uid'],
                        :token => omniauth['credentials']['token'],
                        :secret => omniauth['credentials']['secret'])
end
def build_twitter(omniauth)
  Twitter.configure do |config|
    config.consumer_key = TWITTER_KEY
    config.consumer_secret = TWITTER_SECRET
    config.oauth_token = omniauth['credentials']['token']
    config.oauth_token_secret = omniauth['credentials']['secret']
  end
  client = Twitter::Client.new
  self.name = client.current_user.name
end
```

I've added the following to my spec_helper.rb so that I pass the login part of the integration test:

```
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = {
  'provider' => 'twitter',
  'uid' => '12345',
  'credentials' => {
    'token' => '12345',
    'secret' => '54321'
  }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to test the `build_twitter` method which uses the twitter gem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first note is that you can get their twitter name without the twitter gem.  I've renamed the fields (twitter_handle, real_name) to be specific.

```
self.twitter_handle ||= omniauth['user_info']['nickname']
self.real_name = omniauth['user_info']['name']
```

You can then test this with omniauth test mode.  Somewhere in your Cucumber before hooks or rspec helpers

```
  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true

  # the symbol passed to mock_auth is the same as the name of the provider set up in the initializer
  OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:twitter] = {
    "provider"=>"twitter", 
    "uid"=>"1694349", 
    "credentials"=>{
      "token"=>"165349-aRlUJ7TeIb4Ak57oqycgwihqobrzQ0k5EI7", 
      "secret"=>"SNZT7S70xZIhANfZzgHUEpZMPSsGEHw"
    }, 
    "user_info"=>{"nickname"=>"joshcrews", "name"=>"Josh Crews", "location"=>"Nashville, TN", "image"=>"http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/1076036384/josh_profile_franklin_normal.jpg", "description"=>"Christian, Nashville web developer, Ruby", "urls"=>{"Website"=>"http://www.joshcrews.com", "Twitter"=>"http://twitter.com/joshcrews"}}
  }
```

To test, just assert/should that your user's name is now either "joshcrews" or "Josh Crews" depending on what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do know that I'm not being efficient by using the twitter gem and that I can get the name from the omniauth hash but this is an example where I actually want to set up both omniauth and the twitter gem.

Comment: cool.  Well I've got a test for the Twitter gem, but very, very limited.  I use mocha and have 'Twitter::Client.any_instance.expects(:update)' to make sure that method got called during an integration test.

Comment: Is it worth adding another gem/syntax? Mocha looks interesting but I'd like to get back to writing code instead of learning a new testing framework :)